# Selectively ignore debug breaks for specific files in VS2005

Tags: c++, visual-studio, debugging, break

Every time I run a project in debug mode, I get 4 consecutive breaks at the start that I have to hit continue for each time. They are in the same file at the same point.

It would be great if I could say to simply ignore these since they don't impact functionality.

The obviously better route would be to try to resolve it so it doesn't cause a break/continue prompt but I think that's more effort that it's worth at the moment.

It would be great if the solution related only to my specific environment so I wouldn't have to undo/do it each time I pull/push a build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use break point condition or break point filer.

Comment: Ah, that does seem to work. I put a condition on the problem line saying to prompt only if false is true (never).